# C++ Redistributable for Visual Studio 2019

Tags: c++, dynamic, dll, visual-studio-2019

We are using a C++ Dynamic dll in our exe which is compiled using VS2019 (v142) toolset. We would like to know which C++ Redistributable  package should be installed to run this exe.

When we try to execute this exe on a new PC without VS2019 installed, it does not load this C++ Dynamic dll.

We tried installing X86 (vc_redist.x86.exe) from following website to execute this exe but it did not work.
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/windows/latest-supported-vc-redist?view=msvc-170

Any idea which redistributable is required for V142 toolset?

Comment: The redistributable will not work if your application is dependent on the debug runtime. This is not included in the redistributable because you are only supposed to run debug versions on systems that have Visual Studio installed and I mean Visual Studio and not VSCode.

Comment: Please define "it did not work". Is there an error message? [Edit] your question and clarify.

Comment: ***Any idea which redistributable is required for V142 toolset?*** The one you linked is the proper one for any version of msvc included in Visual Studio 2015 to 2022.

Answer (score 0):

The components of vs can be downloaded in the visual studio installer, the C++ Redistributable I use is as follows:

[image]

> When we try to execute this exe on a new PC without VS2019 installed,
> it does not load this C++ Dynamic dll.

DLL needs to be linked before it can be used. For linking method, you could refer to this [document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/build/walkthrough-creating-and-using-a-dynamic-link-library-cpp?view=msvc-170#to-add-the-dll-header-to-your-include-path).